# Configure TeXShop to run a script on the document before typesetting

Tags: texshop, scripts, python

Is it possible to configure TeXshop to automatically run a script on a document at the beginning of the typesetting process? I am interested in having the application run a python script on the document to perform a number of regular expression substitutions, and send the result to TeXShop to typeset.

Slightly more complicated, is it possible to configure TeXShop to do this after expanding any `input` or `include` files into the document?

Comment: The closest solution I can suggest is adding an engine to the "typesetting" engine menu. This lets you run your application if you click on "it." The TeXShop documentation explains how to add an engine to the menu.

Comment: For your second question: as it is not texshop but the (la)tex compiler that reads and expands the ``input`` and ``include``s you cannot configure this in texshop. But it shouldn't be too complicated to imitate the behaviour of ``input`` and ``include`` within your python script or to make your script recognize and follow the ``input`` links.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the question can be addressed by creating a custom script and adding this to the typesetting menu of TeXshop (or indeed any TeX editor). All you are then doing is putting whatever instructions you want to run before a call to `latex` (or similar).

As commented, the second part is not possible directly as your editor doesn't read the TeX files itself: the TeX engine you use (pdfTeX, XeTeX, ...) does that. The nearest you can get is to parse the file yourself before running the typesetting, but this is non-trivial!